# How to communicate between multiple ROS master?

Tags: ros, communication, multiple, master

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two PCs in one robot. The PCs are connected using one router. PC1 is selected as ROS master.

I have another two PCs in another robot. The PCs are connected using another router. PC3 is selected as ROS master.

How to communicate between the ROS sub-networks? How to avoid name conflict?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223371/how-to-communicate-between-multiple-ros-master?/) by [somebodyus](https://answers.ros.org/users/20767/somebodyus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2016-01-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2016-01-02**:
I think...the idea behind networking is that you have only ONE master and so many slaves as you desire.
But to let many masters to communicate each other is not a function of ROS. I think you cannot. Or you must create some communications packets on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will need to use something like [multimaster_fkie](http://wiki.ros.org/multimaster_fkie) or [rocon_multimaster](http://wiki.ros.org/rocon_multimaster) and namespace each of your robots. You can take a look at [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/41433/multiple-robots-simulation-and-navigation/) about the namespacing.

---

Originally posted by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) with karma: 962 on 2016-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0